# Interviewer wants to meet me in person, but no follow-up

Tags: interviewing

I recently had a phone interview for job in a different state. Right after the interview, I got an email from the interviewer saying that he'd like to meet me in person and that I should be contacted regarding travel arrangements soon. I responded thanking him for the interview and agreed to traveling to meet him; however, after a week, I still haven't received any travel plans or any other email. This is a large company whose travel department is in a different state.

How should I go about following-up on the travel arrangements? Should I wait longer or recontact the interviewer or something else?

Edit:
I feel that this question is different from [other questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p) dealing with what to do when you don't get a response after an interview. In this case, I received a response from the interviewer (suggesting I travel to meet him), and I responded to him. However, there was no follow-up. I don't want to appear over-zealous and impatient to the interviewer, especially if his response could simply be "I already sent the request to the travel department; it just takes time for them to process it."

Comment: Contact the hiring manager via email and ask if the travel department of theirs have the right email address and/or phone number for you, as you have not received any communication from them, softly reminding the manager if he/she forgot.

Comment: Why is this question marked down twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reach out to the person who interviewed you ASAP.   It could be that there is a problem with the scheduling or your contact info got lost somewhere along the way.

I'm sure you know this but don't start out with "Where the hell is my travel info!"  Start out the conversation with "I am very excited to meet with you in person regarding this position.  Have you gotten a chance to look at your schedule and determine when a good time will be?"

Good Luck.